# why wouldn't ls work with execvp?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have an assignment requesting me to write a mini-shell - something that will get a command to execute, execute it, and wait for some more commands.

when I pass to this mini-shell the command `ls .` it prints the contest of the current directory. When I pass to it `ls` it prints nothing. Why?

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAX_CMD_SIZE 40
char** parse(char*);//will parse the arguments for the execv/excevp commands.

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    bool debug = false;
    assert(argc <= 2);
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        //check for string -debug
        debug = true; 
    } 
    if (debug)
        printf("INFO: Father started PID[%d]\n", getpid());
    char *command = malloc(MAX_CMD_SIZE);
    while(true)
    {
        printf("minishell> ");
        fgets(command, MAX_CMD_SIZE, stdin);
        if (strcmp(command, "exit\n") == 0)
            return 0;
        pid_t pid = fork();
        assert(pid >= 0); 
        if (pid == 0) //child
        {
            if (debug)
                printf("INFO: Child started PID[%d]\n", getpid());
            char** buf = parse(command);
            if (debug)
            {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; buf[i]; i++)
                    printf("INFO: buf[%d] = %s\n",i,buf[i]);
            }
            execvp(buf[0],buf);
            return 0;
        }
        else //father
        {
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            if (debug)
                printf("INFO: Child with PID[%d]terminated, continue waiting commands\n", pid);
        }
    }
}

char** parse(char *string)
{
    char** ret = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    ret[0] = strtok(string, " ");
    int i = 0;
    for (; ret[i]; ret[i] = strtok(NULL, " \n"))
    {
        ret = realloc(ret, sizeof(char*) * ++i);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Your parse function :O, error comes from here for sure, do a " String to Word tab" function it will be easier for later.

Comment: @Gabson I think so too, but I can't find the error.

Comment: Try running a command with more than one argument; you'll see that only the first one is passed to `execvp`.

Comment: @chepner no. it doesn't happen. tried.

Comment: With `debug`, `ls foo bar` should only show `ls` and `foo` in `buf`.

Comment: @chepner it doesn't. minishell> ls foo buf
INFO: Child started PID[4489]
INFO: buf[0] = ls
INFO: buf[1] = foo
INFO: buf[2] = buf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your parse() command includes a `\n` in the last argument :)

So with a single ls, you're actually executing `ls\n`, which is not in the PATH (of course)

The problem is that on the first `strtok()` call, you only pass `" "` as a delimiter. Use `" \n"` (like in the subsequent calls) and the problem goes away.

You could also fix it by chomping the `\n`:

```
int l = strlen (string);
if (l > 0 && string [l - 1] == '\n') string [l - 1] = '\0';
```

and only using `" "` as a delimiter.

Comment: `strtok`, according to the manual, excludes the delimiter. Any way, I removed the '\n' from the string, recompiled, no change.

Comment: Not the point. Try to change `printf("INFO: buf[%d] = '%s'\n",i,buf[i]);` and run `minishell -d` :) For a single token, it includes the \n.

Comment: `str[strlen(str) - n] = ...` is a dangerous construct. One should make really sure not to pass in a "string" `str` shorter then `n`.

Comment: Yeah. I shouldn't even have suggested the alternative.